# Graphic bugs after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: intel-graphics, thinkpad, 22.10

I am using Lenovo ThinkPad gen 10 with GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P with a resolution: 3840x2400.

With Ubuntu **22.04**, everything was working fine but when I upgraded to 22.10 I had many Graphical glitches issues.

I tried to install Ubuntu **22.10** from scratch and not to upgrade, I tried also to change resolutions, I installed  Ubuntu budgie to try with a different desktop environment but the bug persisted, so I reverted to Ubuntu 22.04. Does someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Screen flickering
>
> Panel Self Refresh (PSR), a power saving feature used by Intel iGPUs
> is known to cause flickering in some instances FS#49628 FS#49371
> FS#50605. A temporary solution is to disable this feature using the
> kernel parameter i915.enable_psr=0.

(https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics)

this solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

As commented by maxpe the bug is caused by PSR to resolve it in ubuntu :

1. sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. in the editor, locate the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add i915.enable_psr=0 to the end of the line. The line should look like this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
3. sudo update-grub

hope that it will be fixed on the next updates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this qualifies as a proper answer. I had similar problem on a desktop (Z490A-SILVER, i7-10700F) with GeForce RTX 3060. Just managed to have running the metapackage nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary, tested) and works fine so far. If there are proprietary drivers for your GPU available for 22.10 using those may solve the issue. I'd done that but I've not gone back to 22.04.